# How to get data from sql in json format

Tags: c#, sql, json

i use the next for getting data from sql db and show it  in console(for example)

```
DataContextDataContext ob = new DataContextDataContext();
foreach (var emp1 in ob.DimProducts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(emp1);
}

foreach (var emp2 in ob.DimProductCategories)
{
     Console.WriteLine(emp2);
}

foreach(var emp3 in ob.DimProductSubcategories)
{
    Console.WriteLine(emp3);
}
```

[image]

How i can convert data to Json ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Some RDBMS have native support for JSON - others not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library and `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` for it.

```
DataContextDataContext ob = new DataContextDataContext();
foreach (var emp1 in ob.DimProducts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp1, Formatting.Indented));
}
foreach (var emp2 in ob.DimProductCategories)
{
     string jsonEmp2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp2, Formatting.Indented)
     Console.WriteLine(jsonEmp2);
}
```

There are many examples in the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm).

You can also install Json.NET from NuGet console:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON Data (SQL Server) - 
I think you can use  like this in your query
Ex:

```
"SELECT name, surname FROM emp FOR JSON AUTO"
```

Result will be like this :

```
    [ 
   { "name": "John" },
   { "name": "Jane", "surname": "Doe" }
]
```

Another example query is

```
  SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'lax $.info')
```

Comment: You need SQL Server 2016 for this though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Azure or Sql Server 2016 you can get JSON directly from the sql server by adding `FOR JSON PATH` to the end of your SQL query.